# Stack overflow when I am trying to make a composite type with a matrix as a field

Tags: julia

In the following code, I have a composite type, and in my real code several of the fields are matrices. In this example is only 1. I keep getting stack overflow when I try constructing the composite type. Here is the code sample:

```
struct Tables
    eij::Array{Float64,2}
end

Tables(eij::Array{Float64,2}) = Tables(eij) # works if this is commented out
x = 5   # arbitrary matrix dimension    
e_ij = Array{Float64,2}(undef,x,x)

for i=1:x
    for j=1:x
        e_ij[i,j] = i*j/2.3     #dummy numbers, but not the case in real code
    end
end

vdwTable = Tables([e_ij[i,j] for i=1:x,j=1:x])
```

I use the temporary variable `e_ij` to make the matrix first since I don't want the composite `Tables` to be mutable. So, my reasoning is that by generating the tables first in dummy variables like `e_ij`, I can then initialize the immutable `Tables` that I really want.

If I comment out the outer constructor for the struct `Tables` it works. However, I actually want to have several different outer constructors for cases where different fields are not passed data to be initialized. In these cases, I want to give them default matrices.

The error I get is the following: `ERROR: LoadError: StackOverflowError:` on 
the line `vdwTable = Tables([e_ij[i,j] for i=1:x,j=1:x])`

Comment: I was basing this on a similar approach I used for composite types with vectors, however, I was also using parametric types. I think the use of parametric types is what made defining the type on the Left Hand Side of the outer constructor work... But I do not know why... If I leave the LHS as Tables() or Tables(eij) it works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a composite type, an inner constructor is automatically defined, so this:

```
struct Tables
    eij::Array{Float64,2}
end
```

is equivalent to this:

```
struct Tables
    eij::Array{Float64,2}
    Tables(eij::Array{Float64,2}) = new(eij)
end
```

When you define *this* outer constructor

```
Tables(eij::Array{Float64,2}) = Tables(eij)
```

you get in the way of the inner constructor. Your outer constructor just calls itself recursively until you get a stack overflow.

Doing this, on the other hand,

```
Tables(eij) = Tables(eij)
```

is actually equivalent to this:

```
Tables(eij::Any) = Tables(eij)
```

so when you subsequently call

```
vdwTable = Tables([e_ij[i,j] for i=1:x,j=1:x])
```

it then just ignores your outer constructor, because there is a more specific method match, namely the *inner* constructor. So that particular outer constructor is quite useless, it will either be ignored, or it will recurse until stack overflow.

The simplest solution is: just don't make an outer constructor. If you *do* need an outer one to enforce some conditions, make sure that it doesn't shadow the inner constructor by having the same type signature. For example,

```
Tables() = Tables(zero(5, 5))
```

should work.

I would probably do it like this, though:

```
struct Tables
    eij::Array{Float64,2}
    Tables(eij=zeros(5, 5)) = new(eij)
end
```

For your second example, with two fields, you can try this:

```
struct Tables
    eij::Array{Float64,2}
    sij::Array{Float64,2}
    Tables(eij=zeros(5,5), sij=zeros(5,5)) = new(eij, sij)
end
```

Your inputs will be converted to `Float64` matrices, *if* that is possible, otherwise an exception will be raised.

Comment: This is a good answer. Question though: What if I want the default zero matrix to be the same size as other matrix? Is there a way to do that in the inner constructor? In the real code, the size of the matrix is not known until runtime. The real question is if I have 3 or more fields, each a matrix, but there is a possibility that only 1 will be passed to the constructor, how do I make the other 2 default zero matrices of the same size as the passed matrix.

Comment: Inner constructor: `Tables(eij=zeros(5, 5), sij=zeros(size(eij))) = new(eij, sij)`

Answer (score 5):

[DNF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749865/dnf) gave a proper explanation so +1. I would just like to add one small comment (not an answer to the question but something that is relevant from my experience), that is too long for a comment.

When you omit specifying an inner constructor yourself Julia automatically defines one inner and one outer constructor:

```
julia> struct Tables
           eij::Array{Float64,2}
       end

julia> methods(Tables)
# 2 methods for generic function "(::Type)":
[1] Tables(eij::Array{Float64,2}) in Main at REPL[1]:2
[2] Tables(eij) in Main at REPL[1]:2
```

while defining an inner constructor suppresses definition of the outer constructor:

```
julia> struct Tables
           eij::Array{Float64,2}
           Tables(eij::Array{Float64,2}) = new(eij)
       end

julia> methods(Tables)
# 1 method for generic function "(::Type)":
[1] Tables(eij::Array{Float64,2}) in Main at REPL[1]:3
```

So the cases are not 100% equivalent. The purpose of the auto-generated outer constructor is to perform an automatic conversion of its argument if it is possible, see e.g. (this is the result in the first case - when no inner constructor was defined):

```
julia> @code_lowered Tables([true false
       true false])
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (Core.apply_type)(Main.Array, Main.Float64, 2)
│   %2 = (Base.convert)(%1, eij)
│   %3 = %new(Main.Tables, %2)
└──      return %3
)
```

while in the second case the same call would throw a method error.

Comment: Huh. I actually didn't know about the default _outer_ constructor. But knowing that re-enforces a lesson I'm gradually learning: try to write as little and as simple code as possible, and see if it 'just works'. Then add methods as needed. Otherwise you just get in the way of yourself.

Comment: This is exactly also my experience - Julia has pretty sensible defaults most of the time :). There is one corner case related to this with parametric types https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17186#issuecomment-286300768, but it is more advanced and hopefully gets fixed one day.